# Upgrading hard disk, installing/activating Windows 8.1 that is installed on old hard disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have an old hard disk inside my laptop. Currently there is Windows XP installed on it, but I would like to install Windows 8.1.

If i install Windows 8.1 I have (on DVD), on to this old hard disk, will I be able to install and activate same Windows on new hard disk? So, its not like installing one Windows OS on two computers, but its just like moving Windows to another hard drive. Because I plan to buy new, larger memory hard disk in future.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just get the new HDD and install direct to that?

Comment: No;  Your Windows XP license is tied to the machine in question.  if that isn't your question then please clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Its not the Xp I am worried about. I plan to remove Xp, and do the clean install of Windows 8.1 on this old hard disk i am using currently. But in the future I am planning to buy larger hard disk, and I wonder how could I move then Windows from old hard disk to new one. Thanks.

Comment: @Shevek Well yes, that is the best scenario. And I will certainly buy new hard disk in future, when I'll have money for it :). But, now, I have Windows 8.1 installation disk, and activation key with it, and would like to try it on hard disk I use currently.

Comment: If all you plan on doing is replace the hdd you can do that with any verison of Windows.

Comment: You should even be able to put your new HDD in a USB enclosure, clone your existing drive to it, swap the new HDD into the laptop and carry on as you were, without the need to re-install again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do that, as you will erase the partition on old hard drive to not use that activated Windows and have to fresh installation on new HD. It will just require your Windows Key which you got via Email or either on the cover of DVD from MS to activate it.

A reference link from [MS site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-do-you-transfer-windows-8-licence-to-a-new/1424b725-4aa2-4c93-a559-1b35542d72a7).